# How to add cmake options on Windows?

Tags: linux, cmake, cmakelists-options

I need to build a library for Linux and Windows with options FIRST_OPTION=1 and SECOND_OPTION=1.

For Linux I just use:

```
make FIRST_OPTION=1 SECOND_OPTION=1
```

And everything works OK

For Windows I use cmake and Visual Studio:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A Win32 -S D:\lib60870-2.3.1\lib60870-C -B "build32"
cmake --build build32 --config Release
```

But where to put options in this command on cmake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out:

```
cmake -SECOND_OPTION=1 -FIRST_OPTION=1 -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A Win32 -B "build32"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add variables at configure time with `-D` flag.

```
cmake -D SECOND_OPTION=1 -D FIRST_OPTION=1 -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A Win32 -S D:\lib60870-2.3.1\lib60870-C -B "build32"
cmake --build build32 --config Release
```

Comment: `-D` option in CMake doesn't introduces "compile definitions". Such option introduces CMake **variable**, which can be used in `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Right, thanks for the correction.